# Spacing between Silver Birches?

Tags: trees, planting

I'd like to plant a small silver birch forest in my little garden.  I'm going to plant two rows zigzagging the trees.  What is the closest spacing I can use between the silver birches.  Thank you

Comment: Which variety of Birch will  you be using?